# react native custom TextInput onchangeText Not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native

This is My template code

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {TextInput, View, Text,} from 'react-native';

const InputT = ({ label , inputvalue, ipOnChangeText, placeholder , secureTextEntry}) => {
    const {inputStyle, labelStyle, containerStyle} = styles;
    return(
        <View style = {containerStyle}>
            <Text style= {labelStyle} >{label}</Text>
            <TextInput 
               secureTextEntry={secureTextEntry}
               autoCorrect={false}
               placeholder={placeholder}
               style= {inputStyle}
               value = {inputvalue}
               onChangeText = {ipOnChangeText}
            />
        </View>
    );
 }

const styles ={
    inputStyle:{
        color: '#333',
        fontSize: 16,
        lineHeight: 23,  
        borderBottomColor: '#333',
        borderBottomWidth: 0.5,
        fontFamily: 'System',
    },
    labelStyle:{
        fontSize: 18,
        color: '#737373',
        paddingBottom: 10,
        fontFamily: 'System',
    },
    containerStyle:{
        flexDirection: 'column',
        marginTop: 10,
        marginBottom: 10
    }
}
export { InputT };
```

Comment: I fixed your formatting. Please do that yourself next time. Would be better for you to describe what you expect to happen with this code and more specifically how it is broken.

Comment: are you getting any error?

Comment: yes  i  am  getting error    .when  i  call this template our  login form  all  is  fine  but  onChangeText  event  is  not  working  .here is  my code =>  
                    <InputT
                        label= "Team Size"
                        placeholder= "eg:10"
                        value = {this.state.teamsize}
                        onChangeText = {teamsize => this.setState({ teamsize })}
                    />

Answer (score 4):

Based on your question and your comment I think you are passing the wrong property. Change your login form to:

```
<InputT 
  label= "Team Size" 
  placeholder= "eg:10" 
  value = {this.state.teamsize} 
  ipOnChangeText = {teamsize => this.setState({ teamsize })} 
/>
```

Notice how I changed `onChangeText` for `ipOnChangeText` which is the name of the property your `InputT` component is expecting